# Does creating a clustered index break my application

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning-advisor

I am using the SQL Server 2008 R2 Database tuning advisor to tune one database which is used by a 3 rd party ERP system. At the moment this ERP application does have some serious performance issues in specific actions performed by users.

I used SQL Server profiles to trace their production database for few hours during busy time of the day. Last night I let the database tuning advisor chew the trace and it came up with a lot of recommendations and a promised performance gain of 89% !!

So now, I have understand that from the recommendations I should first create recommended clustered and unique indexes and then redo the trace and tuning.

Is it possible that by creating a clustered index I some how break the application functionality ?

Comment: what kind of database is that? every normal OLTP oriented table should have an clustered index (mostly something like Id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered for example). also you should use the tuning advisor for hints, not for blind execution of recommondations

Comment: There are only few clustered index in whole database, and this database have few tables with over one million rows. Not that much of rows, but I think application would run faster with better indexes.

These tables do have a "Unique, Non-Clustered Index" for this pk column, but tuning advisor thinks that i should create a clustered index to this same column

Comment: And for question, this is a database used by an erp application which is done with .NET. It handles crm,sales,invoicing,production management, stock management and so on.

 So it is in pretty heavy use. And it does have few extremely slow functions which take minutes to complete.

Comment: don't create a second, clustered one, better change your existing to clustered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that by creating a clustered index I some how break the application functionality ?

No, creating CLUSTERED INDEX / UNIQUE INDEX certainly won't break your application from a functional perspective since these would be helpful during retrievals where the index would be consulted instead of performing a table scan. They don't impose any constraint on how the data should be stored in the tables like integrity constraints (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE KEY, FOREIGN KEY etc.,).

Comment: Thanks, I will start by doing the suggested clustered indexes first and lets see how does that affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Clustered index may break app performance in case of update and insert new records. Clustered index tell SQL to place records in order as defined in clustered index.

If new records will break this order, SQL must move many records in table to ensure clustered index order for each new record.